# mobiscroll angularjs Error: f.mobiscroll is not a function

Tags: angularjs, mobiscroll

I've just downloaded Mobiscroll with angular js integration ( I've used this in the past without angularjs ).

I'm following the instructions at http://docs.mobiscroll.com/2-13-0/ng-integration, and am getting the following error:

Error: f.mobiscroll is not a function
mobiscroll.ng.getDDO/<.link@http://example.com/includes/mobiscroll.angular/js/mobiscroll.custom-2.13.0.min.js:122:433 .....

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

I recently also had this "is not a function" problem.
It's because the mobiscroll function is added to the JQuery prototype function, but JQLite doesn't have this function.
If you load the JQuery before angular, angular will use JQuery as JQLite, so that you can successfully call mobiscroll function.